# Whats the difference between `yum groupinstall` vs regular `yum install`?

Tags: linux, installation, yum

Whats the difference between `yum groupinstall` vs. regular `yum install`?

Answer (score 20):

Assuming you're talking about `yum`, the `groupinstall` command installs a bundle of packages that are designated as a group so that you don't need to install a bunch of individual packages yourself to have all of the features.  So `yum groupinstall "Engineering and Scientific"` would install a bunch of packages that someone decided should be used on engineering and scientific workstations.  Likewise `yum groupupdate "Engineering and Scientific"` would upgrade those packages if necessary (and install any new ones) and `yum groupremove "Engineering and Scientific"` would remove all of them.

`yum grouplist` will list the possible groups.  `yum groupinfo groupname` will show what packages are members of `groupname` (you will need "quotes" if there are spaces in the group name).

More details [here](http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2006/07/23/viewing-package-groupings-with-yum/) (grouplist and groupinfo) and [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-centos-fedora-linux-yum-command-howto/)

The regular install just installs individual packages (and their dependencies) by name.

Personally, I think individual packages are the way to go unless you aren't sure what package you want, and want to try all of the Editors to see which one you like.